# wp_nav_menu_items filter :: custom menus fall outside ul class

Tags: menus

I'm adding extra menu items by using WP's filter `wp_nav_menu_items` but the menus fall outside the ul class.

My code is as follows:

```
     function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    global $mytheme_option; 

    $layout = $kiwi_theme_option['home-blocks-logged']['enabled'];

    if ($args->theme_location == 'vendor_navigation') {

        if ($layout && $args->theme_location == 'top_navigation'): foreach ($layout as $key=>$value) {               
            switch($key) {   
                case 'cart': 
                    $items_icon = get_template_part( 'templates/topbar', 'rolecart' ); 
                break;  

                case 'dashboard': 
                    $items_icon = get_template_part( 'templates/topbar', 'roledashboard' );
                break;       
            }    
        }        
        endif;

    }   

    return $items_icon . $items;    

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
```

However, it will look like this in the source code:
[image: Image - Source Code]

I'm using Redux framework field sorter:

[Stackoverflow :: Redux sorter - retrieve dynamic pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805238/redux-sorter-retrieve-dynamic-pages)

[Redux sorter field](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/sorter/)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are these lines:

```
$items_icon = get_template_part( 'templates/topbar', 'rolecart' ); 
$items_icon = get_template_part( 'templates/topbar', 'roledashboard' );
```

where you expect `get_template_part()` to return the output, but it doesn't, because it's basically a wrapper for `require()` and `require_once()` calls.

This means the template parts are not part of the returned filter value.

I agree that the `get_` prefix is confusing here!

It would make more sense to have it `the_template_part()` instead ;-)

Here's some hacking with output buffering. Let's use the `wpse_return_` prefix it emphasize that it **returns** the output:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'wpse_return_template_part' ) )
{
    function wpse_return_template_part( $first = '', $second = '' )
    {
        ob_start();
        get_template_part( $first, $second );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

and then

```
if( function_exists( 'wpse_return_template_part' ) )
    $items_icon = wpse_return_template_part( 'templates/topbar', 'rolecart' );
```

Comment: What should I use instead of `get_template_part` then?

Comment: move the parts into the filter callback as variables or hack with output buffering are two workarounds @kiarashi

Comment: I almost got it working... Please see my answer below.

Comment: It should be sufficient to only check once for the function's existence,  Wrap your code inside the filter callback with it, but leave the return out of it @kiarashi

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out. You were quicker with your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really struggled with this problem. :)

Comment: you're welcome, glad to you hear you had procress on the problem @kiarashi